# Match Columns of different workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am now creating new macro. I still have difficulties

Anyway, I have two workbooks.

1. Customer List
2. Account List

on Customer List I have columns

```
Cust_No, Cust_ShortName, Cust_fname, Cust_mname, Cust_lname, Cust_Bdate, Cust_Address
```

while on Account List I have

```
CusT_NO, Acct_Name, Acct_No, Date_Created, Balance
```

Now... I want to match them using there Cust_NO. I want to get the ACCT_NO from the Account List. (by the way Cust_NO is unique so that's my basis for matching)

I want to copy Customer List and save as new file, but before copying it I want the Acct_No should be included in the new saved file.

I want it like this for the new file:

(New Saved file) columns

```
Cust_No, **Acct_No.**, Cust_ShortName, Cust_fname, Cust_mname, Cust_lname, Cust_Bdate, Cust_Address
```

Comment: "I am now creating new macro" - please share it and explain what it currently does, and how it should work different.(please don't answer in comment, but edit your question).

Comment: So, you basically need a vlookup in another file?

Comment: yes I did. I also filter the data then delete all the blanks after I'd write down vlookup. thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to automate the process to be run regularly there is no need for a macro. You just need to open both files and create a VLOOKUP in the file you want your results in.

Comment: thank you. already did what you've said. and it worked out well. the output shows I really want. thanks a lot